# Как gdb работает с результатами команды print?

Tags: linux, c, gdb

Я знаю что gdb позволяет печатать результат выполнения выражения посредством `print <exp>`. Такой результат потом можно повторно использовать (через `$N`). Теперь допустим у меня есть такие функции:

```
const char* foo(){ return "foo";}

char* foo2(){static char b[10]; /*change b*/; return b}

char* foo3(){char* b; /*Create string on heap*/ return b;}
```

Что делает gdb с результатами команд `print foo(), print foo2(), print foo3()`? Как он будет освобождать эти переменные, и не может ли эта очистка привести к ошибкам?

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251729/is-it-safe-to-use-print-command-in-gdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первых двух случаях - нечего освобождать. Все данные в этих случаях у вас имеют статический класс памяти. Они как существовали с момента запуска программы, так и продолжат существовать  до ее завершения.

В третьем случае ничего освобождаться не будет. Побочный эффект вызова - выделение динамической памяти - будет "жить" до завершения выполнения программы, как будто функция была вызвана нормальным образом из вашего кода. (Это, кстати, бывает полезно при отладке - если кто-то "забыл" выделить память, то ее можно выделить вручную вызовом из `gdb` и продолжить выполнение.)

Другими словами, дебаггер просто никогда и не пытается освобождать то, что не выделял сам. Он просто печатает результат функции, ни о чем более не беспокоясь.

Comment: Да, я тоже примерно так думал просто хотел уточнить. Ведь дебаггер не может понять каким образом была получена и строка и как ее очищать